# Movie where a woman is running away from a plant creature which rips her shorts?

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I'm trying to figure out a movie's name.  In the movie there was a woman running away from some plant creature, and she was knocked out.  I remember it tried to rape her and ripped her shorts as its vines grew bigger. I think she managed to cut off the vine and run away.

Answer (score 18):

This sounds like the famous "tree rape scene" from the 1981 film *[The Evil Dead](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083907/)*.  It was the first of the trilogy of humorous horror films made directed by Sam Raimi and starring Bruce Campbell as Ash.

Comment: It's not that movie it's an older movie. The vines didn't grow bigger in evil dead

Answer (score 5):

"There's Nothing Out There!" (1991)

There is a scene just like that in this movie. The creature is green and looks plant-like, a girl has her shorts ripped off and then runs into a tree and knocks herself out.

### Trailer

Comment: It does not really look like a plant, and it rips off her skirt. Its possible, but I dont thing this is it.